# How to convert collection arrays to list<> C#

Tags: c#

I have several arrays to collect data from a postgreSQL query. The data comes from RF receiver deployed in the field. As the user establishes the range of frequencies and time for the query the data is displayed on gridview and passed from there to the arrays indicated by an I value and a I + value matching the cell number in the column containing the latitude of the RF receiver. This data is use to plot xy scatter graphs representing (frequency,amplitude), (frequency,bandwidth) etc. I would like to create a list and objects instead of using arrays.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
dataGridView1.SelectAll();
numCells = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count;
for (i = 14; i < (numCells); i += 14)

{

if (i < numCells)
{

if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToString()== 28.464258839)
{
UCS1size += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToStrin()) == 28.42859146)
{
MOCsize += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToStrin()) == 28.490616471)
{
AMsize += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToStrin()) == 28.525409911)
{
UCS2size += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToStrin()) == 28.560529988)
{
LC40size += 1;
}
}

else
{
MessageBox.Show("exiting for loop. numcells: " + numCells);
}

}
double[] freqLC40 = new double[LC40size];
double[] ampMaxLC40 = new double[LC40size];

double[] freqMOC = new double[MOCsize];
double[] ampMaxMOC = new double[MOCsize];
double[] freqUCS1 = new double[UCS1size];
double[] ampMaxUCS1 = new double[UCS1size];
double[] freqUCS2 = new double[UCS2size];
double[] ampMaxUCS2 = new double[UCS2size];
double[] freqAM = new double[AMsize];
double[] ampMaxAM = new double[AMsize];

int LC40idx = 0;
int MOCidx = 0;
int UCS1idx = 0;
int UCS2idx = 0;
int AMsidx = 0;


for (i = 14; i < (numCells); i += 14)
{

if (i < numCells)
{
if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToString())==  28.464258839)
{
freqUCS1[UCS1idx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCell[i].Value.ToString());
ampMaxUCS1[UCS1idx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i +9].Value.ToString());
UCS1idx += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i +11].Value.ToString()) == 28.42859146)
{
freqMOC[MOCidx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString());
ampMaxMOC[MOCidx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i +9].Value.ToString());
MOCidx += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToString()) == 28.490616471)
{
freqAM[AMsidx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString());

ampMaxAM[AMsidx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 9].Value.ToString());
AMsidx += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToString()) == 28.525409911)
{
freqUCS2[UCS2idx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString());
ampMaxUCS2[UCS2idx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i +9].Value.ToString());
UCS2idx += 1;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 11].Value.ToString()) == 28.560529988)
{
freqLC40[LC40idx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString());
ampMaxLC40[LC40idx] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i+9].Value.ToString());
LC40idx += 1;
}

}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("exiting for loop. numcells: " + numCells);
}

}


//get XY form LC40
xyForm = new XYplotForm();
xyForm.Plot(freqLC40, ampMaxLC40, "LC-40 Max Amplitude");
xyForm.Show();
```

Comment: just create a class with these two properties frequencey and ampMax. Read the grid and create a new class object for a row that you want to display in the chart.

Comment: Well, you can create lists and objects, what stops you and what have you tried by now?

Comment: using `freqUCS1` as an example all you need to declare and instantiate is this `var freqUCS1  = new List<double>();` and to add to it, simply `freqUCS1.add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCell[i].Value.ToString()));`

Comment: Thank you for all inputs will apply and implement.

Comment: After converting to list<double>, plotting doesn't work, says "does not exist in the current context.

Comment: List<double> freqLC40 = new List<double>();
                        freqLC40.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString()));
                        List<double> ampMaxLC40 = new List<double>();
                        ampMaxLC40.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i + 9].Value.ToString()));

Comment: the plotting section    xyForm = new XYplotForm();
            xyForm.Plot(freqLC40, ampMaxLC40 "LC-40 Max Amplitude");
            xyForm.Show();   "the name freqLC40 does not exist in the current context" same for ampMaxLC40.